# Does Crate work only with HTTP protocol?

Tags: crate

I couldn't find this information on tech specs...
Although REST is very convenient to a variety of scenarios, a native protocol sounds like much more high speed. Does the current implementation support native binary protocol ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to use the native transport protocol.
Nodes connecting via this protocol know the cluster state and routing information which makes them faster. Right now, only the Java client supports this protocol.

Generally speaking we found that the HTTP protocol isn't much slower if you connect with high parallelity. Just connect asynchronously with many connections.